# make android application free for some users

Tags: android

I would like to make my application free to install and upgrade for some users only (for example translators, developers and friends, to which else I would have to send the package at every release).

I thought the new licensing would allow that, but it seems not. Since I can't find the answer to whether it is even possible, I am asking right away:
Is it possible to put a paid application on the market and have it either freely istallable or paid, let's say based on the user id (account)?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do would be to just send them an apk that they can install.  They won't get auto updates, but should be able to use it.

Comment: That is what I am actually doing right now. But between transators and testers this gets annoing, since the project gets often upgrades. I was searching for a way to solve that one.

Answer (score 1):

I think I saw somewhere in the documentation for in-app billing that it is possible to have "unmanaged" purchases, where it is up to you to manage which user purchased what, either on the device or on a separate server. Maybe it's possible to implement your own purchase server to run in the "Google cloud" using AppEngine?

Anyway, in-app billing is, AFAIK, not available yet, and it seems a tad complicated just to let your friends try your application for free. I've been considering an alternative approach to implementing a try-before you buy scheme:

a) Implement a free App with basic functionality
b) Implement a paid but otherwise empty "unlock" App
c) When users activate "paid" functionality, use the PackageManager to look for the "unlock" app. If it is installed then activate the requested feature, otherwise show a dialog asking the user to go to the market and buy the unlock app.

If you did something similar, you could tell your friends and your testers to download and/or upgrade the unlocked version, and just send them the .apk for the "unlock" app. Furthermore, you would only need to send them the unlock app once.

I think I've seen such "unlock" apps on the market, but I haven't actually tried the approach myself (yet), so I can't guarantee that it will work. Can't see why it shouldn't, though.

Answer (score 0):

For this, if it's possible, you need to have a database for the userId (if you want to manage that)

Or if you want a freely application.. it will need to be a Freeware (a beta version) from the complete application

Else, i don't think it's possible